# Slim Framework Page Not Found / Apache2

Tags: php, apache, htaccess

Estou usando o [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) gerenciado pelo [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) e ao digitar na URL `http://localhost/app` surge um error **404-Not Found**, se eu digitar `http://localhost/index.php/app` ele funciona.

Oque já fiz?

- Add `AllowOverride All` em `<Directory
  /home/samper/localhost/www>[...]</Directory>` do
  `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` e surgiu o erro **500-Internal Server
  Error**.
- Habilitei o `RewriteBase /` em `/home/samper/localhost/www/vendor/slim/slim/.htaccess` do
  slim e também no `/home/samper/localhost/www/.htaccess` da home
- Copiei o `.htaccess` de `/home/samper/localhost/www/vendor/slim/slim/.htaccess` para `/home/samper/localhost/www/vendor/slim/.htaccess`

**Meu .htaccess** (*/home/samper/localhost/www/.htaccess*)**:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

**Meu apache2.conf** (*/etc/apache2/apache2.conf*)**:**

Obs: aqui não tem o httpd.conf

http://pastebin.com/C1qFkJ6k

**Meu 000-default.conf** (*/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf*)**:**

http://pastebin.com/drPwFUSS

**Meu PHP:**

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
```

**Meu Sistema:**

```
Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description:    elementary OS Freya
Release:    0.3.1
Codename:   freya
```

**Meu Código:**

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development', //production
    'log.enabled' => false,
    'templates.path' => './view',
));

$app->get('/', function() {
    echo "Home";
});

$app->get('/app', function() {
    echo "App";
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Então, mesmo após add o `AllowOverride All` e reiniciar o apache `service apache2 restart` não funcionava devido o `mod_rewrite` não está habilitado.

### Resolvido

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema e foi dificil achar a solução rs.

Comment: conseguiu resolver com este post @mauriciocaserta ? :)

Comment: na verdade já tinha resolvido, mas confirmei aqui! :D

Answer (score -2):

Tive o mesmo problema, isso tb resolveu para mim.

sudo a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart